# How to concatenate multiple field values within Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concatenation

Here is my form

```
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address_1 %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address_1 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address_2 %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address_2 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :city %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :state %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :zip %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :zip %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :country %>
  </div>
```

And this is what I want to do with the input values

```
:address_1 + :address_2 + :city + :state + :country
```

I have tried the following with no success

```
"#{address_1} #{address_2} #{city} .etc"
```

I am trying to join the input values for a more accurate geocoding in the location model

```
 class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    geocoded_by :address_1 <--- should be the ":address_1 + :address_2 + :city + :state + :country" value
    after_validation :geocode

end
```

How do I concatenate these values in the model to be used as such?
Thanks

Comment: You have rails address field stored in your table, and you want to output concatenated?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in following ways

1. make address in model --> this is the best way
2. make address in controller --> this is good way

**Way no 1 in model**

```
attr_accessor :address_1, :address_2, :city, :state, :country

 def before_save
    self.address = @address_1 + " " + @address_2 + " " + @city + " " + @state + " " + @country
 end
in controller

def save
   person = Person.new()
   person.address_1 = params[:address_1]
   person.address_2 = params[:address_2]
   person.city = params[:city]
   person.state = params[:state]
   person.country = params[:country]
   person.save
 end
```

**Way no 2 For example *model person* and *controller Person* in controller**

```
def save
   person = Person.new
   person.address = params[:address_1] + " "params[:address_2] + " " params[:city] + " " + params[:state] + " " + params[:country] 
   person.save
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can write a method like -

```
def full_address
  "#{self.address_1}, #{self.address_2}, #{self.city}"
end
```

Then in your controller or view you can simply apply this method on an instance of your model. Try this in your rails console to see the result.

```
user = User.first #assuming all your fields are stored inside user model
puts user.full_address
```

So in this way, you don't need to save the whole address again. You can always call your `full_address` method, even in your views to get the full address.